# Xubuntu - Libre office - restore Whisker menu entries

Tags: xubuntu, libreoffice, whisker, menulibre

I accidentally deleted two entries LibreOffice (Writer & Calc) from my Whisker menu (via MenuLibre). How can I easily restore them?

Also the file associations for .xls seems to be gone (opens up in Archive Manager) - LibreOffice Writer/Calc is not even in the "Open with Other Application" menu.

A couple days ago I did a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Can you launch any of them from the command line as `libreoffice --calc` or  `libreoffice --writer`?

Comment: yes I can. I tried using that command as "Open with", but it doesn't work for remote locations (http://i.imgur.com/axwxofg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way proved to be copying these menu entries from my other computer running Xubuntu. I simply copied all /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-* files from one machine to another. Even the Open with entry is back now.

I suppose I could have also used the ones I didn't delete in first place (LibreOffice Math) and just substitute some values.

Comment: My other comment was to make sure that you still had it installed.  Then I was going to write you an answer to have you recreate the two missing .desktop files, but since you beat me to it, no worries.  =)